# Динамическая кастомизация документации в Swagger UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

Дано - API для внутреннего пользования, сваггер, кастомный JSON-сериалайзер и пара атрибутов, которыми этот сериалайзер руководствуется.
Требуется - строить документацию в сваггере руководствуясь теми же атрибутами, что и сериалайзер.

**DTO**

```
public class MyDto
{

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ShortModelMember]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    ...
```

**API метод**

```
    [ReturnShortModel]
    [HttpGet]
    public MyDto GetMyDto()
    {
        return new MyDto();
    }
```

Сеарилизованы будут только те проперти, которые помечены атрибутом `[ShortModelMember]`, однако в примере и модели ответа в Swagger UI по-прежнему будет отображаться полная структура класса. Как это решить? Есть мысль, что с помощью фильтров (*Schema, Operation, Document*), но как там настроить именно *example/model* да ещё и для конкретных методов апи - пробовал разобраться, но пока не смог.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё что нужно - это написать класс-реализацию `IOperationFilter` и зарегистрировать его. Следующее решение позволяет использовать разное представление одной и той же модели в **Examples** апи метода в **Swagger UI**.

---

**Реализация нашего фильтра**

```
public class SwaggerExcludeFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        if (!apiDescription.GetControllerAndActionAttributes<ReturnShortModelAttribute>().Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        var responseType = apiDescription.ResponseDescription.DeclaredType;
        var description = $"OK (uses a short model of {responseType})";
        var props = responseType
                    .GetProperties()
                    .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ShortModelMemberAttribute)).Any())
                    .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p.PropertyType.Name);
        }

        operation.responses.Clear();
        operation.responses.Add("200", new Response
        {
            description = description,
            schema = new Schema
            {
                example = props,
            },
        });
    }
}
```

**И не забываем зарегистрировать фильтр**

```
c.OperationFilter<SwaggerExcludeFilter>();
```